# Using jQuery for tooltips

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a div with a form inside it. The form is small, consists of one or two dropdown/textboxes. I'm wondering what would be required to do the following:

- when I click on a link, a tooltip pops up with the form in it. It appears over top of the link that I clicked so that when it appears the mouse is over top of it.
- when the mouse exits the bounds of the tooltip, it disappears.

Doing some googling, all of the tooltip examples I found appear upon hovering over a given area. All the jQuery popup examples I seen are modal and force the user to explicitly close it.

Does anyone know of a way that I can have a tooltip work as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find a plugin that works, what you described is pretty straight forward to implement.

You just have to bind a mousemove event to the document and check to see if its target or its target's parents are your tooltip.

This example is for a trigger button that is right next to the tooltip, but it might work for having it directly over the trigger as the trigger then wouldn't be hovered.

```
$("#trigger").hover(function () {
    // move the tool tip div into place
    // show the tool tip
}, function () {    
    $(document).bind('mousemove.tooltip', function (e)
    {
        if (e.target.id !== 'tooltip' && $(e.target).parents('#tooltip').length === 0)
        {
            // close tooltip
            $("#tooltip").hide();
            $(document).unbind('mousemove.tooltip');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a rudimentary fiddle that works as described:

http://jsfiddle.net/5h3Zy/5/

Comment: The problem I'm having with this approach is that as soon as the tooltip is displayed, it hides because the browser thinks the cursor is outside of the box. This has been tested in IE9 and Chrome, both exhibit this behaviour. I also had this problem by specifying an onmouseout handler for the div.

Comment: The code I took this sample from is a little different. The trigger is a button next to the tooltip, so when the trigger button is hovered, it has a hover event which shows the box. The unhover part of the function then declares the mousemove handler. I'll add that to the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com) plugin use a dialog and a function such as the following:

```
$("#yourDialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$("#yourLink").click(function(){
      $("#yourDialog").open();
});

$("#yourDialog").mouseover(function() {
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).close();  
});
```

Comment: This does not work since 'open' cannot be found. Is this reliant on a 3rd party library?

Comment: It is using the jquery ui dialog control.

Comment: @Evan, you should edit your answer and mention that it's dependent on including jQuery UI... not everyone using jQuery will necessarily be using jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well i Creted something that i guess was what you where after take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/hDcac/1/

The code got kinda messy but you shuld get the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mylink').hover(function () {
        $('#mytooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $('#mytooltip').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#mytooltip').hover(function () {
        $('#mytooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $('#mytooltip').fadeOut();
    });
})
</script>
<div id="mylink">My Link</div>
<div id="mytooltip'">My Form</div>
```

This puts a "hover" event on each element. Anytime your mouse is over either element, it calls "stop(true,true)" which prevents the fadeOut from occuring. Once the mouse leaves the elements, the tooltip fades.